# Windows 7 not switching to full screen

Tags: windows-7, fullscreen

When I try to load up a full screen program, no matter what it is, it will automatically minimize and

- A. flicker on and off of the screen and then remain in the task bar
  *or*
- B. flicker on and off of the screen and then appear in window form again with a funky size that does not fill the whole window.

I tried disconnecting my monitor and checking my res, all were fine.

One thing to note is that YouTube goes into full screen with no problems. Don't know what that's about.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: So F11 for example doesn't make your browser or Windows Explorer go fullscreen properly?

Comment: Is it a sudden incident or it happens since you installed Windows 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lately, my computer was getting more messy with BSODs and the such, so I blew out the insides, and then ran a memory check to find any corrupted sectors. I had a few, and next time I booted it up it worked! Also, a few other minor problems were fixed.